# Python sockets, attribute error str has no attribute encrypt

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encrypt'

when running these lines of code. They are inside definition of a function(except for the import lines). Btw from which library is the function `encrypt()`?

```
 import socket
 import sys
 import getopt
 import threading
 import subprocess
     buffer="lol"
     client_sender(buffer.encrypt('utf-8'))
```

Comment: And client_sender function definition is not important here, it later passess its argument to socket which sends it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to go with

```
buffer.encode('utf8')
```

in order to make the string a byte object and pass it to a socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) to a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object, the proper method is [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
>>> s = "foo"
>>> s.encode("utf-8")
b'foo'
```